# Flutter not building for version 1.10 or higher

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I updated my flutter version to the latest and then I get following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Failed to parse host [PROXY SERVER] systemProp.http.proxyPort=[PROXY PORT]
Warning: Failed to parse host [PROXY SERVER] systemProp.http.proxyPort=[PROXY PORT]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

It also creates this error when I create a fresh project. I tried different versions of flutter and version 1.9.7 works. Later versions create all the same error.
It seems to be a problem with gradle. With gradle 3.2.1 everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to your proxy configuration as indicated in the warnings at the first 5 lines.

Review your proxy configuration in gradle.properties

Comment: I don't use any proxies and I also didn't configure any proxy settings in gradle.properties.

Comment: @RaphaelThurnherr have you checked the gradle.properties inside android folder of the project and gradle.properties inside user directory? (in windows it is C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\gradle.properties)

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you so much. I was wasting so many hours and didn't know there was an other gradle.properties in the user directory. In Linux it is  ~/.gradle.

Comment: @RaphaelThurnherr You are welcome, the gradle.properties in user directory can come in handy when you use the same proxy config  for all your projects.